How high can baseboard heaters be installed?
I'm trying to do a basement loop to heat up my basement. Can I install a hot water baseboard at approx. 12" from the floor?

This seems like an XY question. Consider asking about your reason for doing so instead. Maybe there's no need.

My elementary school gym had hot water radiators halfway up the walls of the gym to provide protection of them from gym activities, and to keep the hot water away from children possibly getting burned.  So as long as you have decent air movement in your basement, I don't see why there would be any restriction on maximum height above the floor.  And some natural convection of air getting heated will help the warmer air circulate throughout the space, and not just above the radiator level.

This is probably an aesthetic question more than anything else.  Something sold as a baseboard may look terrible if you put it higher.  It may have an unpainted underside, it's connections may appear exposed and ugly.  Conversely, radiators designed for high wall mounting are usually priced very high as architectural features with chrome fittings or hidden fittings and no visible brackets or unfinished surfaces.

Sure you can.
Expect to have cold feet, since there's no reason for the cold air sitting on the floor to move if the baseboards are set a foot above it. Circulation will pretty much stop at the intake height of the baseboards, unless you run a ceiling fan or something for mixing.

Well, there will be some updraft mixing. As witness the euro-style wall plate heaters that seem to be in fashion for bathrooms. I won't attempt to guess whether that would be enough.

I'm not an HVAC technician, but I know of no common code restriction that would prohibit doing so. It's also true that many radiant heaters are taller than 12", so such a limitation would be odd.
Of course, we have no idea where you are or what local codes are at play. You might ask your community's inspection office.
